# How to get all CPT names into WP_Query 'post_type' parameter?

Tags: post-type

hello

I want to display post based on his ID. This post could be a default 'post', 'page' or other registered custom post type. In query I sould specify all CPT names which I want to use, for eg.

```
 'post_type' => array('post', 'page', 'my_cpt')
```

My question is how can I set 'post_types' automatically for all registered post types, without manually specify them?

I'm striving for something like that:

```
$post_types = ALL-POST-TYPES-NAMES;
$the_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => $post_types,
    'p' => ID,
  )
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of post types with the [`get_post_types()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) function:

```
$post_types = get_post_types();
```

In your case you'll want to set the second `$output` parameter to `names` (since that's what you need to pass to the `post_type` argument), and you'll probably want to set the `$args` in the first argument so that only public post types are returned, otherwise you could end up with weird stuff like menu items and revisions:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( [ 'public' => true ], 'names' );
```

However, it looks like you're just looking for a specific post based on the ID. If that's the case, then you don't need post types or a query at all. Just pass the ID to `get_post()`:

```
$post = get_post( $id );
```